# org.json.JSONException: No value for content

Tags: java, android, json

I'm getting an error stating "org.json.JSONException: No value for content" however I've checked the JSON response I'm getting and it contains the value content:

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/M41q4blaJ7w/comments?v=2&alt=json&start-index=1&max-results=50&prettyprint=true

I'm not sure exactly what I've done wrong - I must have formatted something incorrectly but I'm not sure what it might be.

SOURCE:

```
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        try {

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(
                    "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/"
                            + video_id
                            + "/comments?v=2&alt=json&start-index=1&max-results=50&prettyprint=true");

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

            String jsonString = StreamUtils.convertToString(response
                    .getEntity().getContent());

            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
            JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONObject("content").getJSONArray(
                    "name");

            List<Comments> comments = new ArrayList<Comments>();

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
                String content = jsonObject.getString("content");
                String published = jsonObject.getString("published");

                comments.add(new Comments(name, content, published));
            }

            CommentsLibrary lib = new CommentsLibrary(jsonString, jsonString, jsonString);

            Bundle data = new Bundle();
            data.putSerializable(LIBRARY, lib);

            Message msg = Message.obtain();
            msg.setData(data);
            replyTo.sendMessage(msg);

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Log.e("Feck", e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Feck", e);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("Feck", e);
        }
        return null;
    }

    /*
     * @see android.os.AsyncTask#onPostExecute(java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        TextView nameTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);   
        nameTv.setText(com.idg.omv.domain.CommentsLibrary.getName());

        TextView contentTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.content); 
        contentTv.setText(com.idg.omv.domain.CommentsLibrary.getContent());

        TextView publishedTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.published); 
        publishedTv.setText(com.idg.omv.domain.CommentsLibrary.getPublished());
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You do not have the key content for every json object. so instead of `getString("content")`,

use **`optString("content","defaultValue")`**

In this case, if there is no value for content, then you return a default value

Comment: String content = jsonObject.optString("content","defaultValue");

results in: org.json.JSONException: No value for content

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the `JSONObject "content"` because it is a nested object in the JSON string you provided.

From what I see you would first have to get the `JSONObject "feed"` then the `JSONArray "entry"` and only then you can invoke `.getJSONObject("content")` on one of the objects in the array.

**EDIT**

To get to the name it gets a little tricky, because the name seems to be even further down in the object.

Once you have the `JSONArray "entry"` try the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) { 
    JSONObject entry = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i); 
    JSONObject contentObject = entry.getJSONObject("content");
    String content = contentObject.getString("$t");

    JSONObject publishedObject = entry.getJSONObject("published");
    String published = publishedObject.getString("$t");

    JSONArray authorArray = entry.getJSONArray("author");
    JSONObject authorObject = authorArray.getJSONObject(0);
    JSONObject nameObject = authorObject.getJSONObject("name");
    String name = nameObject.getString("$t");

    comments.add(new Comments(name, content, published));
}
```

I do have to say it's a bit of a hassle, but this should work, let me know if you need more help.

If you try to parse JSON Objects always pay attention to the format:

- If something starts with a `{` its another `JSONObject`
- If something starts with a `[` it's a `JSONArray`
- If something starts with `"` then you are finally at the string and can invoke `.getString()` on the identifier.

Comment: I tried using JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONObject("feed").getJSONArray("entry");
    List<Comments> comments = new ArrayList<Comments>();

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
     JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

     String name = jsonObject.getString("name");

and ended up getting org.json.JSONException: No value for name

Comment: @user3009687 I'll add the solution to my answer above.

Comment: I also added how to get the content and published string.

Comment: Strange... I just used exactly what you posted and it isn't populating the textview: http://pastebin.com/r6DydbRH

Comment: @user3009687 Try again now, I made a minor mistake in the code, it's fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

This is the structure of your json :-
[image]

I am parsing your url and i do this :-

```
JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
JSONObject json2 = json.getJSONObject("feed");
```

Now, as you can see from the above image, object **feed** has an array named **entry**
Now, json2 is not returning the array `entry` as seen in the image below, and i cannot hardcode your json in assets folder and parse it because it is encoded in SP1252 encoding and eclipse is showing an error.
[image]

Your json is also dynamic, so it is sometimes coming valid and sometimes not.